# Last transformation not executed on CompletableFuture when completeExceptionally is called

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I have following code:

```java
public final class Start {

    private static final CountDownLatch FINAL_THREAD = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private static String getValue() {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(1).toMillis());
            return "value";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return "interrupted";
        }
    }

    private static void whenComplete(String value, Throwable ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
            System.out.println("whenComplete Ex: " + ex);
        } else {
            System.out.println("whenComplete Value: " + value);
        }
    }

    private static String handle(String value, Throwable ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
            System.out.println("handle Ex: " + ex);
        } else {
            System.out.println("handle Value: " + value);
        }
        FINAL_THREAD.countDown();
        return value;
    }

    private static String peek(String value) {
        System.out.println("peek: " + value);
        return value;
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> createRequest() {
        System.out.println("Create....");
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Start::getValue)
                .thenApply(Start::peek)
                .handle(Start::handle)
                .whenComplete(Start::whenComplete);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        createRequest().completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("TEST"));
        FINAL_THREAD.await();
    }

}
```

When I execute it I get output like this:

```
> Task :Start.main()
Create....
Waiting...
peek: value
handle Value: value

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
```

I don't understand why `Start::whenComplete` is not called when both `Start::peek` and `Start::handle` are. If I switch handle with whenComplete then `Start::handle` will not be called, but `Start::whenComplete` will. I would expect that `Start::whenComplete` will be called with `RuntimeExeception` in this case, while other stages will be executed with value provided by `Start::getValue`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation of `CompletableFuture` covers this, but let's slowly get to it, as it is not that trivial. First we need to refactor slightly your code:

```
private static CompletableFuture<String> createRequest() {
    System.out.println("Create....");
    CompletableFuture<String> one = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Start::getValue);
    CompletableFuture<String> two = one.thenApply(Start::peek);
    CompletableFuture<String> three = two.handle(Start::handle);
    CompletableFuture<String> four = three.whenComplete(Start::whenComplete);

    return four;
}
```

And let's slightly change your `main` too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> f = createRequest();
    boolean didI = f.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("TEST"));
    System.out.println("have I completed it? : " + didI);
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5));
}
```

Now let's carefully looks at this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> four = three.whenComplete(Start::whenComplete);
```

via the documentation of `whenComplete`:

> Returns a new CompletionStage with the same result or exception as this stage, that executes the given action when this stage completes.

breaking it into smaller pieces:

> Returns a new CompletionStage (`four`) with the same result or exception as this stage (`three`), that executes the given action (`Start::whenComplete`) when this stage (`three`) completes.

Who is supposed to execute `Start::whenComplete`? According to the documentation : `four`. When is it supposed to execute it? When `three` is completed.

---

According to your flow, *before* `three` is completed, you `completeExceptionally` your `four`. So when `three` is done, so is `four` - meaning it can't execute that `Start::whenComplete` (`action`); simply because it is already completed. Another way to think about it is that when your code reaches this line:

```
CompletableFuture<String> four = three.whenComplete(Start::whenComplete);
```

`four` is an un-completed future. It can be completed in two ways:

- either when `three` is completed, thus triggering `Start::whenComplete`
- externally (what you do with `completeExceptionally`)

Because you complete it externally *before* `three` is completed, it will not run that action.

---

If you chain an action to the future *that you complete*:

```
four.whenComplete(Start::whenComplete);
```

this is when you will see the desired output.